# 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I will be working with candidates to arrange a proper time.

***The Town Hall Chat will take place Wednesday the 19th at 18:00:00Z UTC / 2:00 PM EDT.***

**[view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=9&day=19&year=2012&hour=18&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)**

**[register here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/5860/web-applications-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)**

**[join the room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5860/web-applications-town-hall-chat)**

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the primary phase.  This means that I am looking at the 17th-19th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=webapps.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: Sounds good! I should be there to answer any questions you guys have for me!

Comment: I won't be here for the chat, but I'm baffled by one candidate's promise, *"I promise to always publish conversations with other members and moderators,"* which seems to suggest one can't expect privacy when contacting moderators.  I'd like to hear the other candidates thoughts on privacy vs transparency.

Comment: Certainly a valid concern, @Adam. We'll make sure this is raised in the chat-cast!

Comment: Haha, just read the chat. Very amusing - it was probably a good thing I wasn't there, I don't think I could have resisted poking the hornet's nest...

Comment: Is there a transcript available?

Comment: @AlEverett There is a digest version that will be available soon - Sathya is currently answering and when that is finished, we'll be able to post up the digest.

Comment: @Grace: Awesome. Thanks.